# Is there any easy way to clone all elements of a list inside itself?

Tags: c#, list

For example,

```
new List<int>{1,2,3,4} -> new List<int>{1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4}
```

Of course, I know it can be easy with a loop. But is there any more efficient way to do this?

Comment: "Elegance" is in the eye of the beholder and not a good measurement by which to judge answers. Please [edit] your question to include a measurable way of describing the difference you are looking for.

Comment: Do you want to create a new list or to modify the existing list?

Comment: If you want to create a new list you can just do `var newList = list.Concat(list).ToList();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to modify the existing list, you can do;

```
var list = new List<int>{1,2,3,4};
list.AddRange(list.ToList());
```

Note that it is necessary to copy the list (with [`ToList()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.tolist?view=net-6.0) or some other way), otherwise you end up modifying the same list while [`AddRange`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.addrange?view=net-6.0) iterate over it to add elements.

If you want to create a new list, use [`Concat`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.concat?view=net-6.0)

```
var list = new List<int>{1,2,3,4};
var newList = list.Concat(list).ToList();
```

Comment: Upvoted, as your answer is correct and you are making the point of defensively considering the case that the list is adding its own elements, which can break any logic that assumes its immutability in the context of the loop. I have also made this point in my answer, but, I was using a constructor instead of the `ToList` that your answer suggests.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `.AddRange()` method,

```
List<int> input = new List<int>(){1,2,3,4};
var result = new List<int>(input);
result.AddRange(input);

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", result));
```

---

If you want to include in the same List, then you can directly apply `.AddRange()` to input list itself.

```
input.AddRange(input);
```

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for [AddRange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.addrange?view=net-6.0):

```
list.AddRange(new List<yourtype>(list));
```

In the code above I have cloned `list` because under the hood, there must be a loop that traverses `list`'s elements and add them to itself. So, in theory I can imagine cases of looping the list and infinitely adding the newly added elements, but when you do actual coding, it's worth testing whether

```
list.AddRange(list);
```

also works well. If so, then cloning the list is unnecessary. If not, then you need to clone.